# How to cast byte image from google colabs upload to array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, google-colaboratory

So i want to make a function that show a preprocessed version of uploaded images by google.colabs.files.upload() method . But it gives me an error when trying to do some open-cv operations, turns out the image is some byte-type variable. I tried to cast it to numpy array and doesn't work, so what is the correct way to cast it?

P.S its okay if you don't give me explanation i just want the code because the deadline for the task is near

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want (no explanation)

```py
from google.colab import files
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im= files.upload()
im= Image.open(BytesIO(list(im.values())[0]))
im= np.array(im)
```